# Toggle Show Date and Time via AppleScript

Tags: applescript

How can I toggle the "Show date and time in menu bar" option via AppleScript. I'm using OSX 10.10.4.

I am looking for a working example in AppleScript.

Comment: toggle between date and time showing ?

Comment: The option to hide or show the date and time in the menu bar.

Comment: There are three ways to do it. Use GUI scripting to access the checkbox inside System Preferences. Or use `defaults write` to change `com.apple.systemuiserver` and then `killall systemuiserver`. A commercial solution is Bartender.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that's working on my elderly MacMini'09. "delay" may have to be adjusted ...

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    tell application "Finder" to set position of window 1 of process ¬
        "System Preferences" to {1200, 1000}
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.datetime"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    delay 0.5
    click checkbox "Datum und Uhrzeit in der Menüleiste anzeigen" of ¬
        tab group of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

- I left German strings in the script to avoid home-brew English "translations" > DIY !
- Directly upon System-Preferences' launching, its app window is "hidden" to some corner
- There's a delay as otherwise things would not work before the final shutdown ...

... Oh, btw, I would recommend to install a keyboard shortcut via Automator/services (all apps)